# Using Windows right-click keyboard button on macOS

Tags: macos, keyboard, windows, shortcut

Is there any possible way to assign the Windows right-click keyboard button on macOS in order to use it as a shortcut?

Comment: What differentiates a 'windows right click button' from any other?

Comment: While not specifically “right click” these are all potential dupes:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249375/mouse-middle-click-in-mac-os-misson-control-and-close-tab-at-the-same-time-ho/249378#249378 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84157/how-can-i-remap-the-right-mouse-button-to-the-left-mouse-button

Comment: Also... https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287609/i-have-a-two-mouses-one-for-each-hand-how-can-i-set-the-primary-mouse-button-s/287612#287612 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/385158/make-launchpad-appear-on-screen-with-mouse/385428#385428

Comment: @Tetsujin I would like to use the key on the keyboard and not the key on the mouse

Comment: What kind of keyboard do you have?

Comment: Do you mean you want to [remap a keyboard key to right click](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9228/using-caps-lock-key-instead-of-right-click-contextual-menu)?

Comment: @nohillside logitech g410 atlas

Comment: @Allan no, windows keyboards have typically a key that is ment for the same purpose as the right click on the mouse is... and i want to use that on mac.

Comment: I've never seen a Windows-specific keyboard with such a key, but if there were one, it ought to generate a right-click, the same as a mouse.

Comment: I know exactly what the [Windows *Menu Key*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) is, but that's not is not what you originally asked.  You wanted to know how to reassign "right click" to something else, which has already been asked/answered several time.  Now, the scope has changed to remapping a key to a mouse event, and that too, has also been asked.  Can you *please* [edit] your question so that you clearly state what you're after?

Comment: I got it but maybe it’s bc I was looking for it too years ago. Maybe you should ask for a shortcut to open the context menu on curso position/focus in Finder.

Answer (score 2):

The Menu key is mapped to this key combination by [default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key):

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

However, it is very Windows specific and seemingly only implemented in Microsoft applications on macOS. This will follow the cursor location in applications that support it, whereas right click implementations on Mac usually follow the mouse pointer.